# IHttpResponse through RequestContext not setting HttpOnly = false in a cookie

Tags: servicestack

I´m trying to share a cookie between the server and the client (angularjs, javascript), the only way I figure it out to do it is by setting up HttpOnly = false,in SS when I use **service.RequestContext.Get();**  it seems like no matter what value I´m trying to set the cookie, the value always will be setted as httpOnly = true.

if I use the old **HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add** writes the cookie ok, but to me that's not an option since I would prefer to use IHttpResponse.

please, take a look to the code:

```
public override object Logout(IServiceBase service, ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth request)
            { 
               var resp =service.RequestContext.Get<IHttpResponse>();
               resp.Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie { Name = "r", Path = "/", Value = "from server", HttpOnly = false, Discard = false, Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12) });
               return base.Logout(service, request);
            }
```

the question is, that flag isn´t working because I´m accesing the **IHttpResponse** via **RequestContext**, is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a config option in ServiceStack which lets you control this setting for Cookies. Try setting:

```
Config.AllowNonHttpOnlyCookies = true;
```